# div Draggable et Rezible : doesn't work with containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable, containment

I want a resizable and draggable `div` on a bigger `div` that is contained in a little `div` (to have a scroll Bar) like this:

```
<div id="hgcScroll"  style="width:600px;overflow:auto">
    <div id="hgcRegle" style="width:800px">
    </div>
    <div id="hgcDeplacable">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my jQuery I have this:

```
$("#hgcDeplacable").resizable();
$("#hgcDeplacable").draggable();

$("#hgcDeplacable").draggable({ 
    containment: "#hgcScroll",
    axis: "x",
    grid: [5, 0]

}).resizable({
    containment: "#hgcScroll",
    handles: 'e, w',
    grid: nbrPxDeplac
});
```

But containment of the resizable makes all the application crash, and if I erase the condition containment my handles work just for "e" but not for "w".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: syntax error. remove the } before .resizeable

Comment: error wasn't here :( but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have removed the two first line and i have separate the two methodes like this :

```
$("#hgcDeplacable").resizable({
handles: 'e, w',
grid: 5});
$("#hgcDeplacable").draggable({ 
containment: "#hgcScroll",
axis: "x",
grid: [5, 0]
});
```

And it's work. If you have any questions, ask to me.